# Mystery of a disappearing modal form

Tags: c#, winforms

In this WinForms project, I have a certain information form (`InfoForm`) which pops up for 2 seconds, then disappears.  The way I do this is by calling

```
infoForm.Show();
```

and then inside `InfoForm` I have a `Timer` that ticks after 2 seconds and calls `Close()`.

Now, sometimes there's another form `ErrorForm` I need to show modally (using `errorForm.ShowDialog()`), to inform the user that an error has occurred, and they need to click OK before they can continue.  This can happen while the `InfoForm` is opening and closing, and the one should not affect the other.

But it does.

I have gone so far as to put a breakpoint on the call to `ShowDialog`, and if the `InfoForm` is open at the time that I hit the breakpoint, then when I click 'Step Over', instead of popping up the `ErrorForm` and waiting for me to click "OK", the debugger just steps over the line and is already on the next line, as if the form never opened.  Meanwhile in the background the `InfoForm` has closed, so if I reset the execution point to the call to `ErrorForm.ShowDialog()`, and then "Step Over", the form appears, as expected, and waits for me to click "OK" before moving to the next statement.

Removing breakpoints and writing to a debug log confirms my suspicion that it's the closing of the `InfoForm` that is causing my `ErrorForm` to be untimely closed:

> Thread 09 - 2011/12/14 16:39:30.574 - Info form shown
>
> Thread 09 - 2011/12/14 16:39:31.300 - Before ErrorForm.ShowDialog
>
> Thread 09 - 2011/12/14 16:39:32.584 - Timer Tick
>
> Thread 09 - 2011/12/14 16:39:32.585 - Info form closing
>
> Thread 09 - 2011/12/14 16:39:32.593 - Error form closing
>
> Thread 09 - 2011/12/14 16:39:32.593 - After ErrorForm.ShowDialog

Why is this happening, and what is the cure?

Comment: And you're sure you didn't cross-link an event somewhere? Reproduce it a small (new) project and when you really have something then post it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the `MainForm` as owner to `ErrorForm.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: It is true that the owner of the ErrorForm is being passed as null, but even so, why does the ErrorForm close when the InfoForm does?  Does passing a null owner merely make the new form assume that the last opened form is its owner?

Comment: @Shaul - Yes, from the docs for ShowDialog without params: "Shows the form as a modal dialog box with the currently active window set as its owner."